# How do I delete an imageview so that it no longer exists?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-view

For some certain reasons, I have created some `ImageViews` and assigned specific IDs to them (1, 2, 3, 4, ......). Now I want to COMPLETELY DESTROY those `ImageViews` so that I can assign the IDs (1, 2, 3, 4, ......) to other `ImageViews`. Can anyone tell me how to delete an `ImageView` so that it no longer exists?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: add your code for those imageview!!

Comment: Are you creating the `ImageView`s dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code.

```
View image_view= view.findViewById(R.id.id_OF_IMAGEVIEW);
((ViewGroup) namebar.getParent()).removeView(image_view);
```

Hope this helps you..